# Regex for Name text box in registration form

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Which allows Single Space between two words like "Naresh Kumar" Doesn't allow Special Characters and Number.

Doesn't allow empty Field and Space at Start of string

Comment: We're not here to do your (home)work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
Regex.Match(name, @"^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

[a-zA-Z]+ : means any letter one or more times.
\s : single space
^ : beginning
$ : end